# Creator still uses old compiler even though I've updated my kit

Tags: qt, gcc, qt-creator, qmake

I had a kit set up in Qt Creator 3.0.1 that pointed to my cross toolchain. This worked until I ran into a [bug in the compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57086) and now have to upgrade to a newer version.

I've obtained a newer toolchain. I went into Creator, edited my kit, and updated the path to the compiler and gdb binary to point to the new toolchain.

However, when I build my project, it's still calling the old toolchain's compiler.

I've even completely deleted my kit, compiler, and debugger and recreated their configuration, but no joy.

I double-checked the mkspec that is being used, and there is nothing in there with hardcoded paths to the compiler, just things like `QMAKE_CXX = $${CROSS_COMPILE}g++`. I don't have the CROSS_COMPILE variable set. I did try setting it (in Creator's build environment editor) but no joy there either.

How do I get Creator to use my new toolchain?

**EDIT - NEW INFO**

I tried running the same qmake command line Creator does when it builds (according to its build output). First, the call to qmake I'm making is returning to the command line without creating a makefile. Here is the command I'm running:

```
/qt5/bin/qmake /s/src/tfs/porject_dirs/Myproject.pro -r -spec devices/linux-am335x-g++ CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
```

So, I added a `-d` to get some qmake debug output. I found some fishy lines that pointed to some files that are in my mkspecs directory.

What are these files that were installed when I built Qt?

```
qconfig.pri
qdevice.pri
qfeatures.pri
qmodules.pri
```

Three of the four (not `qfeatures.pri`) include in them hard coded paths to the compiler I used to build Qt. I suspect that these are my problem.

Why does Qt Creator allow a compiler to be specified if these files might be overriding it? Is it safe to edit these files? Do I have to rebuild Qt simply to change the compiler used to build my application?

Comment: I have a nagging suspicion that the qmake binary has the cross-compiler hardcoded into it somehow. I'm not 100%, but I've already encountered issues trying to cross-develop with Qt.

Comment: I guess you've already wiped your build and tried again?

Comment: What Mitch said: your build doesn't have a dependency on the Qt Creator's settings file. Whatever you changed in Qt Creator won't have effects on the build until you re-do it from scratch. Simply `rm -rf` the build directory.

Comment: Yes, I have deletes the build directory multiple times during the course of troubleshooting.

Comment: I discovered some additional information and edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, an [open bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31986) in Qt that leaves hardcoded paths in the `.pri` files mentioned in my question.

---

**Update**
The [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31986) has been resolved.